# object LimitIterator - OutOfBoundsException

Tags: php, foreach, spl

How can I write a condition that not to run the `foreach` below if the object LimitIterator is empty?

```
$numbers = array(5, 19, 8, 35, 50);

$iterator = new ArrayIterator($numbers);

$limiter = new LimitIterator($iterator, 5, 2);

foreach($limiter as $number)
{
    echo $number.'<br/>';
}
```

The code above returns this error,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OutOfBoundsException' with message 'Seek position 5 is out of range' in ..
OutOfBoundsException: Seek position 5 is out of range in..
```

I just don't want to run the `foreach` if the object LimitIterator is empty.

**EDIT:**

Why does `$limiter->valid();` always return `false`? I have the code below running on a [page](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/iterator.php) on my site,

```
$numbers = array(5, 19, 8, 35, 50);

$iterator = new ArrayIterator($numbers);

$limiter = new LimitIterator($iterator, 0, 2);

var_dump($limiter->valid());

if ($limiter->valid()) 
{
    foreach($limiter as $number)
    {
        echo $number.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop writing tags and thanks.. I see that you've been doing it for most if not all of your 184 questions ;(

Comment: is it the rule here not to thank??

Comment: Yes. SO is not a forum or chat, but a _knowledge resource_; the only thing you see in a question should be a question. Contributing back to the community by voting and answering questions is ample thanks. You do not see "thanks" in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OutOfBoundsException` is thrown when the `LimitIterator` tries to seek to the starting offset after rewinding, at the very beginning of the `foreach` loop.

If you want to test to see if the seek position is okay, then either `rewind()` or manually `seek()` within a `try/catch` block.

```
try {
    $limiter->rewind();
} catch (OutOfBoundsException $e) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Of course, you could instead *wrap your `foreach` loop in a `try/catch` block*.

---

> Why does `$limiter->valid();` always return `false`?

It does not **always** return `false`, only when it is not at a valid positon.

The `LimitIterator` in your script, at the point of calling `valid()`, has not been told to move anywhere along itself nor the inner iterator. Until `rewind()` or `seek()` has been called, there is no way for it to be at a valid position.

Comment: I can see [you're the authority](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53926), so can you explain why it doesn't just stop iterating at the end like a regular `foreach` loop?  This kind of ruins the functionality with regards to pagination.

Answer (score -1):

Surely, if it's empty, the `foreach` will be a no-op.

If you insist, you can check that the first element is valid, as alex demonstrated:

```
$limiter->valid()
```

but this should be completely unnecessary.

If neither of these approaches "work" for you, then something else is wrong.

---

Perhaps the real problem here is that you are *not* checking that the underlying container actually has seven elements to iterate.

I don't know enough about `LimitIterator` to be sure, but my experience with C++ iterators is that once you go beyond the reasonable bounds of the underlying container, all bets are off. Perhaps this is why `$limiter->valid()` is "not working" for you?

Comment: it always returns `boolean false` if you test it with `var_dump()` eg: `var_dump($limiter->valid());`

Comment: @lauthiamkok: It does not always return false. It returns `false` only when the "current element" is not valid. [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/limititerator.valid.php)'s the documentation.

Comment: Please see my edit above - can you explain why I get `false`?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: ([live example](http://www.ideone.com/rwawW)) Hmm, no. Investigating.

Comment: @lauthiamkok: [This](http://www.ideone.com/fKjc0) is interesting. I've taken the example from [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/limititerator.construct.php), which works, and added only a reference to `->valid()`, which returns false. I can only assume that `->valid()` is either broken or does not do what we think it does.

Comment: probably it is a PHP bug! :-)

Comment: @lauthiamkok: Possibly. Usually I'd dismiss such a suggestion out of hand -- suggestions of language/infrastructure bugs almost universally turn out to be programmer bugs -- but this functionality is still quite new, and borderline undocumented.

Comment: Undocumented is a problem! I will try to work around this `not to run the foreach` problem! thanks.

Comment: @lauthiamkok - it's not a bug at all, at least the displayed behaviour is what is supposed to happen. That such behaviour (which won't be limited [pardon the pun] to the `LimitIterator`) isn't documented is, however, a bug in the documentation.